# 1.9 - Not all products showing on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute

I have done everything I've found here and elsewhere:

- All products are enabled
- All products are In Stock with 1+ quantity
- All products are set to Catalog, Search
- I have reindexed multiple times, as well as tried reindexing via shell
- I have cleared cache multiple times
- All products are in active categories

For example, in the admin panel, a specific category shows 662 products, but on the frontend it only shows 337.  It's becoming annoying because some filterable attributes only show a few items when used, despite there being many more.

The items are there when searched for using advanced search. They are not there when using attributes to filter for them.

Comment: Check the website, storeview product config and also the product attributes

Comment: Do you have multiple stores or websites?

Comment: One single store/website.

Comment: Also, all the attributes are there and show on the product page. The filter just won’t filter them by it.

Comment: Just a guess, but usually merchants are not really willing to create 662+ products by hand - so I would assume these have been imported? In that case - did you try to save the products again from backend as this sounds a lot like a broken import script to me...

Comment: Not imported, but rather my site is a multi vendor marketplace. So the products were added by vendors. Forgot to mention this in the original post.